# LinearLayout inside ScrollView has random height

Tags: android

I have a `ScrollView` and a `LinearLayout` with an ImageView and some Buttons, the problem is that the ScrollView fills the screen correctly while the LinearLayout has a random height that makes it scrollable even if it shouldn't (since the elements are all inside the screen). This is my xml:

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@drawable/bgapp"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:scaleType="fitXY" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="192dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

       <Button
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@color/transWhite"
        android:text="aaa"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/bbb" />

       <Button
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@color/transWhite"
        android:text="bbb"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/bbb" />

       <Button
        android:id="@+id/asd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@color/transWhite"
        android:text="asd"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/bbb" />

       <Button
        android:id="@+id/ccc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@color/transWhite"
        android:text="ccc"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/ccc" />

       <Button
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@color/transWhite"
        android:text="test"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/ccc" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I already tried to set the `layout_width` and `layout_height` of the LinearLayout to `wrap_content` but with 0 results.. What's wrong with the xml?

Comment: Have you tried to put `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` to your `ScrollView` ?

Comment: Set android:layout_height="fill_parent" to your ScrollView and android:layout_height="wrap_content" to your LinearLayout

Comment: I run your layout on my android app, it works well. Have you tried to remove the android:scaleType="fitXY" in the linearlayout, or use the "show layout bounds" in the developer options to debug, or print the heights of every components in the layout to see which one makes a random height.

Comment: I think the layout_width of liner layout should be wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

In scrolView width and height should be matchparent.  Keep scrollview child to wrap content intead of doing hardcoding, controll image sizes from drawables.